# PHP/MYSQL : Left Join not getting proper parent details

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

```
SELECT smirt.id as mid,
pc.packet_name as pname, 
pcs.packet_name as mainn, 
smirt.p_status as st , 
smirt.new_value as weight , 
smirt.packet_id, 
smirt.parent_packet_id 
FROM issue_receive_process AS smirt 
LEFT JOIN packet_creation AS pc ON  pc.id = smirt.packet_id
LEFT JOIN packet_creation AS pcs ON pcs.id = pc.parent_packet_id 
WHERE smirt.type = 53
AND smirt.main_kapan_id IN(1,2) 
ORDER BY smirt.packet_id
```

From above query i am getting below details :

[image: From above query i am getting this which i dont want]

But above is **wrong**

As pname  is my sub-packet 
and  mainn is my MAIN PACKET

Actually i need  ( should be )  pname (NULL , 0004)  AND mainn ( 0003,0002 ) as below (below image is edit image):

[image: right query]

as 0003 , 0002 are main packet and 0004 is subpacket of 0002 ... 0003 doesn't have any subpacket ....

can any help me where i am wrong.

Thanks

**UPDATE** : PARENT TABLE IMAGE thats ( issue_receive_process AS smirt )

[image: PARENT]

**AS PER USER : KISHORE BELOW QUERY :**

```
SELECT smirt.id
,smirt.packet_id
,smirt.main_kapan_id
,pc.id
,pc.packet_name
,pc.parent_packet_id 
FROM issue_receive_process AS smirt 
LEFT JOIN packet_creation AS pc ON  pc.id = smirt.packet_id
WHERE pc.packet_name IN ('0002','0003','0004') 
ORDER BY smirt.packet_id
```

BELOW IS THE RESULT :

[image: RESULT]

**Second Update table :** packet_creation below details as per below query

```
SELECT *
FROM `packet_creation`
WHERE `id`
IN ( 5, 11, 9 )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the matching data for the packet_creation table as well. At least enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sir, packet_creation table has many data in it ..ok let me see ..thanks for reply ..will try and put it here just min

Comment: Looking at the test data, for the record with mid of 4 the packet_id is 5. Packet_id 5 has a packet name of '0003' (hence pname of '0003') and a parent packet id of 0. However there is no record on packet_creation for id of 0, hence no matching parent packet, hence  mainn is null. Based on this the results you are getting are correct for the data you have.

Comment: sir, from top ... first image is wrong .. second image is what i want ( which i have shown with editing ).... 0003 and 0002 with parent_packet_id is 0 .. where as 0004 have parent packet id as 9 ... hence  0002 is main packet and 0004 is sub packet .. which is of 0002....so final output should be pname: (NULL,0004) which contain subpacket details ..where mainn: (0003,0002) which are mainpacket..but what i am getting is from top 1 images which is worng

Comment: Inshort i need as below :
mainpacket : subpacket ---- (0003,0002)  : (NULL,0004)... hence 0003,0002 are main packet where as 0004 is subpacket of 0002... 0003(main packet ) does not have any subpacket hence its NULL..... but what i am getting is (NULL ,0002) : (0003,0004) which is wrong ... as 0003 is my main packet which should be (0003,0002) : (NULL,0004),....hope u understand

Comment: i have puted all information ..then why -1..please let me know why..

Comment: But your record does not have a parent_packet_id that exists. You appear to want a NULL returned where a record is found (ie packet_creation AS pc) and a value returned where no record is found packet_creation AS pcs). Your pc record is found with the current data hence the value of pname. But the parent_id is 0 which does not exist so mainn is null.

Comment: so can u guide me in order to get mainpacket (0003,0002) : subpacket(NULL,0004)...what i need to do as pname is subpacket column and mainn is mainpacket column and data which i am getting is wrong as 0003 is shown in pname which is wrong as it is main packet and it should be seen in mainn column ..please help me

Comment: You might find it useful to write [a SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so we can see the data you are working with, and to make it easy for people to try changes.

Comment: Mainn field refers to the parent. But the problem is that your first returned row has NO parent. It is getting confusing as you appear to be referring to the parent packet as the sub packet. All I can think of is that you want the child to be the parent if no parent exists

Comment: sir... i know might be confusing this ..its category and sub category .. in my case i want to so all my main category in mainn and all sub category of resp. category in pname ... so finally out will be mainn : pname = (0003,0002) : (NULL,0004) but which i am not getting ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting very confused about what you want.

The SQL you have will give the data that you describe as wrong when run with your test data. It is getting a record and the packet to go with that, and then that packets parent. If the packet doesn't have a parent then NULL is (and should be) returned.

The only thing I can think that you want is that if there is no parent record then you want the child packet id returned as the parent packet id with the child returned as NULL.

If so something like this:-

```
SELECT smirt.id as mid,
        IF(pcs.packet_name IS NULL, NULL, pc.packet_name) as pname, 
        IF(pcs.packet_name IS NULL, pc.packet_name, pcs.packet_name) as mainn, 
        smirt.p_status as st , 
        smirt.new_value as weight , 
        smirt.packet_id, 
        smirt.parent_packet_id 
FROM issue_receive_process AS smirt 
LEFT JOIN packet_creation AS pc ON  pc.id = smirt.packet_id
LEFT JOIN packet_creation AS pcs ON pcs.id = pc.parent_packet_id 
WHERE smirt.type = 53
AND smirt.main_kapan_id IN(1,2) 
ORDER BY smirt.packet_id
```

AS PER ABOVE QUERY RESULT IS BELOW :

[image]

HENCE FINAL OUTPUT I GOT BUT ITS COMING AS 3,4,2 but should be 0003,0002,0004

[image]

EDIT - casting the fields to char to try and force the leading zeros:-

```
SELECT smirt.id as mid,
        IF(pcs.packet_name IS NULL, NULL, CAST(pc.packet_name AS CHAR)) as pname, 
        IF(pcs.packet_name IS NULL, CAST(pc.packet_name AS CHAR), CAST(pcs.packet_name AS CHAR)) as mainn, 
        smirt.p_status as st , 
        smirt.new_value as weight , 
        smirt.packet_id, 
        smirt.parent_packet_id 
FROM issue_receive_process AS smirt 
LEFT JOIN packet_creation AS pc ON  pc.id = smirt.packet_id
LEFT JOIN packet_creation AS pcs ON pcs.id = pc.parent_packet_id 
WHERE smirt.type = 53
AND smirt.main_kapan_id IN(1,2) 
ORDER BY smirt.packet_id
```

Comment: might be your right its bit confusing to explain me : .. sir what i am getting is pname : mainn  = ( 0003,0004) : (NULL,0002).. where pname is subpacket(thats sub catgeory) and mainn is main packet (thats main category)... but actually 0003 is to be main packet and should be shown in mainn column but it showing in pname (subpacket ) list ..hence as 0003 is main packet ... i should get result as pname(sub packet ) : mainn (main packet ) = (null,0004) : (0003,0002)  ..,.which i am not getting :(

Comment: sir i have putted query image in your answer .. also i got what i wanted from above your query .. but but i am getting result as 3,4,2 but should be 0003,0004,0002 ..where my zeros are gone :( now..pls help me...also please explain me in easy manager what was wrong and i was missing ..so that i can change same in all my other pages :) thanks for support till now ..only 0002,0003 then its marked as solved :)

Comment: sir you there ... only 000 are missing now ... how to get back that with above your query

Comment: Not sure what is happening there as when I try that I do get the leading zeros. You could try casting the fields to CHAR in the query (I am adding the suggested code for that).

Comment: DONE :)... THANKS FOR YOUR GREAT GREAT SUPPORT :) THANKS ONCE AGAIN